# displaying errors using flash notifications while retaining input variable

Tags: php

this is my form to validate login

```
function validate_user_login()
{

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if (isset($_SESSION['csrf_token']) && $_POST['csrf_token'] === $_SESSION['csrf_token']) {

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            if (empty($email)) {
                $errors[] = "Email is required";
            } elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $errors[] = "Email format is invalid";
            }

            if (empty($password)) {
                $errors[] = "Password is required";
            }

            if (!empty($errors)) {
                
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    
                    set_message($error, DANGER);
                    redirect_to_url("/user/login");
                    
                }

            } else if (login_user($email, $password)) {

               redirect_to_url("/");

            } else {

               set_message("Email or Password is not valid", DANGER);
               redirect_to_url("/user/login");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have recently added flash messages to control all messages error or success to simplify the code

```
/**
 * @param $message
 * @param string $type
 */
function set_message($message, $type = 'success')
{
    if (!empty($message)) {
        $_SESSION['flash_notification'] = '<div class="alert alert-'. $type .'">'.$message.'</div>';
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['flash_notification']);
    }
}


/**
 * Display message
 */
function display_message()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash_notification'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['flash_notification'];
        unset($_SESSION['flash_notification']);
    }
}
```

everything is working however it refuses to show all required fields, it only shows the first one.

Also I use the site redirect to redirect back to page if there is an error. and cannot get the post data to stay in the input value

```
<?php echo $_POST['email'] ?? ''; ?>
```

Comment: Redirects don't remember the previous requests data. If you want to transfer those values back while redirecting, you'd have to store them in the session too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set_message` only set the last message in your $errors

To store all messages, you need to make $_SESSION['flash_notification'] an array:

```
function set_message($message, $type = 'success')
{
    if (!empty($message)) {
        $_SESSION['flash_notification'][] = '<div class="alert alert-'. $type .'">'.$message.'</div>';
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['flash_notification']);
    }
}
```

And display_message show an array of messages:

```
function display_message()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash_notification'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['flash_notification'] as $notification) {
            echo $notification;
        }
            
        unset($_SESSION['flash_notification']);
    }
}
```

Also call `redirect_to_url("/user/login")` outside the foreach:

```
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                set_message($error, DANGER);
            }
            redirect_to_url("/user/login");
```

Comment: it still provided same result

Comment: I edited my answer... the `redirect_to_url` need to be called outside the foreach to do not interrupt the loop

Comment: Thanks Rafael could you give some advice on keeping the data in the field if there is and error so they dont have to keep re entering like if on the register page email is ok but username is not still keep the username and email in the value?

Comment: You can save the correct values in your `$_SESSION`  (like `$_SESSION['email_input'] = $email`) and fill the respective input value. This way the user will not need to fill the correct value again.

Comment: would i save this in the function or the form input? i tried form value but it wasn't there I am a little new to php

Comment: you save the values in the function ( if the values are valids) and in the input you can make something like `<input type='text' value=<?=$_SESSION['email_input'] ?? '' ?> />`

Comment: was unsuccessful for now ill just change my errors around thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228971/discussion-between-da-don-and-rafael-dourado-d).